# How do I apply an orange blur effect to a div that is encapsulating my image? with CSS

Tags: html, css

How do I apply an orange blur effect to a div that is encapsulating my image? I don't want to apply anything to the image, just to its background div

```html
<div class="image-container">
   <img class="image" src="/assets/images/person.png" />
</div>
```

I'm expecting something similar to this, a slight orange effect all around

[image]

Comment: Why not use a [CSS Gradient for this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient)? Just add the gradient as the background to the `image-container`.

Comment: if you have a transparent png image you can use img{background-color : rgba(215, 146, 112, 0.5);}

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `linear-gradient` for the background of the container of the image. You'll need to make sure that the image only shows the subject, & has a transparent background, otherwise the gradient won't show because it'll be layered under the image.

Here's an example I created: [Image & gradient background](https://codepen.io/jufrench/pen/BaEKdNx)

This is the gradient that I used: `background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,165,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%)`

There are many sites that generate gradients for you. I used this one: [cssgradient.io](https://cssgradient.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope to understand properly.
To do this, we use `gradient` that have 4 types:

```css
.image-container {
  background: rgb(252, 168, 75);
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(252, 168, 75, 1) 10%,
    rgba(255, 231, 208, 1) 100%
  );
}
```

In this code I used `linear gradient`.
If you have a little trouble making it, use the `gradient Online tools` to start and play with them a little.
I hope you have answered your question and got it.